# Call a function B from inside function A, and make B do something when A starts and finishes

Tags: javascript

Given the following code...

```
function logger = ??

function doSomething() {
  logger("doSomething")
  console.log("Middle of doing something")
}
```

Is it possible to define `logger` such that the following output is produced?

```
"started function doSomething"
"Middle of doing something"
"finished function doSomething"
```

I've considered the following:

- Encapsulating `doSomething` in another function that prints first line, calls `doSomething` while passing the arguments, then prints last line.
- Doing the same thing previously mentioned but with a decorator so it's prettier.
- Sending an event at the end of `doSomething` to notify logger it finished and using async code to do that (this one was kind of a shot in the dark, not sure about it)

It was hinted to me during an interview that this is possible via "something to do with heap and the call stack".

Is there a solution that does not involve `doSomething` telling `logger` when it has finished?

Comment: _"it has to do with heap and memory"_: what? How are you meant to get that from the question?

Comment: @Andy No idea, but even so, how do I even solve it with heap and memory? It seems impossible to me.

Edit: I meant heap and call stack when I wrote it.
It was edited out though, so I'll add here:

The interviewer has hinted after the fact that the solution has to do with heap and the call stack, but I still can't see how

Comment: Why "async"? If you don't have anything asynchronous in `doSomething`, it makes no sense to make the whole thing asynchronous... Can you explain?

Comment: Questions about JavaScript should not even mention "the heap": it is of no concern to the coder.

Comment: This question makes sense in other languages, but not in JavaScript. For example, in C++, this would be possible by making `logger` a macro which allocates a local variable in `doSomething`'s scope, an instance of some class whose destructor could handle the final `finished function` message when the variable goes out of scope. We would say that variable was allocated on the stack though, not the heap. However this is completely unrelated to JavaScript which has no preprocessor macros, and no destructors for objects...

Comment: ... This is why decorators exist. It's practically the canonical example of what decorators enable in the language, ie https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-decorators-what-they-are/

Comment: @user229044 Yeah is was pretty sure he meant a decorator so I tried that first, they don't even work with JavaScript for the role I was trying for but since I didn't know much about the language they work with (C#) he asked me about JavaScript which I work with. He was very confusing overall, I must assume a miscommunication happened here, we didn't really vibe well. I guess it happens, thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: @TGPerson If you have the ability to do so, it might be nice to reach out and ask the interviewer if they had any specific answer they were looking for. If nothing else, it might help them stop giving a bad question in subsequent interviews.

Comment: @user229044 I actually probably will have another interview with him because other people in the company liked me so I'll get the chance to ask him, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I've considered ... Encapsulating ... with a decorator ...

That's the way to go.

> Sending an event at the end of `doSomething` to notify logger it finished and using async code...

Using asynchronous code is only relevant when you already have an asynchronous API involved in `doSomething`.

> Is there a solution that does not involve `doSomething` telling logger when it has finished?

That's the basic idea of decorators.

Example:

```js
let logger = console.log;

// Decorator
function logged(task) {
    return function(...args) {
        logger("starting " + task.name);
        const result = task(...args);
        logger("ending " + task.name);
        return result;
    };
}

// Your function -- unaware of logger
function doSomething(arg) {
  console.log("Middle of doing something with argument " + arg);
  return arg.toUpperCase();
}

// Decorating...
doSomething = logged(doSomething);

// Run...
let result = doSomething("test");
console.log(result);
```

#### More features...

There are many extensions/features you can add. For instance:

- Include a generic `decorator` function that takes the target function and any number of decorators as arguments;
- The name of the decorated function could be made equal to the original function name;
- A decorator can decide to perform some action in a `finally` block
- ...

```js
let logger = console.log;

// Generic decorator function
function decorate(target, ...decorators) {
    return decorators.reduce((acc, decorator) =>
        // Propagate target function name
        Object.defineProperty(decorator(acc), "name", { 
            value: target.name
        })
    , target);
}

// Decorator
function logged(task) {
    return function(...args) {
        logger("starting " + task.name);
        let result;
        try {
            result = task(...args);
        } finally { // Also execute in case of error
            logger("ending " + task.name);
        }
        return result;
    };
}

// Your function -- unaware of logger
function doSomething(arg) {
  console.log("Middle of doing something with argument " + arg);
  return arg.toUpperCase();
}

// Decorating with two (same) decorators...
doSomething = decorate(doSomething, logged, logged);

// Run...
let result = doSomething("test");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The `"ending"` log would *not* be printed, if the function being decorated throws some error.

Comment: Indeed, @SSM, that is a choice to make for each specific decorator. In some cases you'd want the action to happen only if no error occurred, in other cases you'd want it to happen still... For a logger decorator I would personally find it counter-intuitive to have the ending logged in case of an uncaught error... but that is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2):

**Decorator handling both synchronous and asynchronous functions**

You can create a decorator function that handles *both* synchronous and asynchronous functions.

In the snippet below, `logger` is a decorator function that takes in a function as it's argument and returns a decorated function that handles the logging.

If the input function returns a `Promise`, it's handled using [Promise.prototype.finally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally).

```js
const logger =
  (func) =>
  (...args) => {
    console.log(`Started: ${func.name}`);
    try {
      const ret = func(...args);
      if (ret instanceof Promise) {
        return ret.finally(() => console.log(`Ended: ${func.name}`));
      }
      console.log(`Ended: ${func.name}`);
      return ret;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Ended: ${func.name}`);
      throw err;
    }
  };

const sleep = (timer) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, timer));

const asyncAdd = logger(async function asyncAdd(a, b) {
  await sleep(1000).then();
  console.log(`Adding ${a} and ${b}`);
  return a + b;
});

const syncSubtraction = logger(function syncSubtraction(a, b) {
  console.log(`Subtracting ${b} from ${a}`);
  return a - b;
});

console.log(`Result of syncSubtraction(2, 1): ${syncSubtraction(2, 1)}`);
console.log("=========================");
asyncAdd(1, 2).then((res) => console.log(`Result of asyncAdd(1, 2): ${res}`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**NOTE:**

1. Using the `finally` method ensures that the *"Ended"* log is printed even if the async function being decorated fails.
2. The `try...catch` block ensures the same thing but for synchronous functions.

```js
const logger =
  (func) =>
  (...args) => {
    console.log(`Started: ${func.name}`);
    try {
      const ret = func(...args);
      if (ret instanceof Promise) {
        return ret.finally(() => console.log(`Ended: ${func.name}`));
      }
      console.log(`Ended: ${func.name}`);
      return ret;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Ended: ${func.name}`);
      throw err;
    }
  };


const syncFail = logger(function syncFail() {
  console.log("Inside syncFail");
  throw new Error("Error in syncFail");
});

const sleep = (timer) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, timer));

const asyncFail = logger(async function asyncFail() {
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log("Inside asyncFail");
  throw new Error("Error in asyncFail");
});

try {
  syncFail();
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
console.log("==========================");
asyncFail().catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Handling error cases differently:**

If you want to handle the error scenario differently than the success one, for example by printing an error log instead of the end log, then refer to the snippet below:

```js
const logger =
  (func) =>
  (...args) => {
    console.log(`Started: ${func.name}`);
    try {
      const ret = func(...args);
      if (ret instanceof Promise) {
        return ret
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(`Ended: ${func.name}`);
            return res;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(`Errored: ${func.name}`);
            throw err;
          });
      }
      console.log(`Ended: ${func.name}`);
      return ret;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Errored: ${func.name}`);
      throw err;
    }
  };

const syncFail = logger(function syncFail() {
  console.log("Inside syncFail");
  throw new Error("Error in syncFail");
});

const sleep = (timer) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, timer));

const asyncFail = logger(async function asyncFail() {
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log("Inside asyncFail");
  throw new Error("Error in asyncFail");
});

try {
  syncFail();
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
console.log("==========================");
asyncFail().catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

There's no change in the behavior of the success scenarios:

```js
const logger =
  (func) =>
  (...args) => {
    console.log(`Started: ${func.name}`);
    try {
      const ret = func(...args);
      if (ret instanceof Promise) {
        return ret
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(`Ended: ${func.name}`);
            return res;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(`Errored: ${func.name}`);
            throw err;
          });
      }
      console.log(`Ended: ${func.name}`);
      return ret;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Errored: ${func.name}`);
      throw err;
    }
  };

const sleep = (timer) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, timer));

const asyncAdd = logger(async function asyncAdd(a, b) {
  await sleep(1000).then();
  console.log(`Adding ${a} and ${b}`);
  return a + b;
});

const syncSubtraction = logger(function syncSubtraction(a, b) {
  console.log(`Subtracting ${b} from ${a}`);
  return a - b;
});

console.log(`Result of syncSubtraction(2, 1): ${syncSubtraction(2, 1)}`);
console.log("=========================");
asyncAdd(1, 2).then((res) => console.log(`Result of asyncAdd(1, 2): ${res}`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just complement @trincot's solution with the asynchronous code handling.

It can wait until the async task will be finished and the wrapped function doesn't know anything about the decorator

```js
const logStarting = (taskName) => console.log("starting " + taskName);

const logFinishing = (taskName) => console.log('ending ' + taskName);

const logFailed = (taskName, e) => console.error('The task: ' + taskName + ' has failed with an error: ', e);

function logged(task) {
  const taskName = task.name;
  if (task.constructor.name === 'AsyncFunction') {
    return async function(...args) {
      logStarting(taskName);
      try {
        const result = await task(...args);
        logFinishing(taskName);
        return result;
      } catch(e) {
        logFailed(taskName, e);
        thrhow e;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return function(...args) {
    logStarting(taskName);
    try {
      const result = task(...args);
      logFinishing(taskName);
      return result;
    } catch(e) {
       logFailed(taskName, e);
       thrhow e;
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after learning about garbage collectors in C# I stumbled upon something that instantly reminded me of this problem. This appears to be the solution:

```js
const registerFinalizer = new FinalizationRegistry(message => {
  console.log(message)
});

function logger() {
  console.log("started function")
  registerFinalizer.register(logger.caller, "finished running")
}

function doSomething() {
  logger()
  console.log("doing stuff")
}


doSomething()

setInterval(function() {

}, 1000)
```

`FinalizationRegistry` basically observes the function and calls the callback once the garbage collector removes the object, which in this case happens some time after the function finished execution.

It was probably the interviewer's way to check my knowledge of the garbage collector, it just doesn't seem like a popular subject in JavaScript, I would never have found this solution if not looking at another language.

Also, apparently it has nothing to do really with logging, and this is probably a bad way to log, it logs that the function `doSomething` has finished running in a big delay since it waits for garbage collector to do his thing, that's why we need the `setInterval` in the end(or any other thing to keep the process running).